# spring tools suite dashboard failed to create parts controls

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-oxygen

Just downloaded and installed STS 3.9.1, linux 64bit version.
Untarred in `/opt/sts_bundle` and chowned to myself.
When I launch it, I get the following errors in the console. And the dashboard pane shows

> Failed to create the part's controls

I believe that it is all related to the class not being found (see below log).
But I do not know how to resolve this.
I have tried using a different workspace, and restarting.

```
mfrederickson@artemis2:/opt/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.1.RELEASE$ ./STS
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/mfrederickson/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.1.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.8.2.20171007-0217.xml
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
09:54:48,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
09:54:48,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
09:54:48,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]
09:54:48,035 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Setting up default configuration.
09:54:48,082 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
09:54:48,087 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[/home/mfrederickson/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.1.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.8.2.20171007-0217.xml]] every 60 seconds. 
09:54:48,087 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
09:54:48,091 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:54:48,091 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
09:54:48,135 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
09:54:48,136 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Could not create an Appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    at ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:73)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:48)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:35)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.begin(AppenderAction.java:54)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:275)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:147)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:129)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
    at  at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:185)
    at  at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at  at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at  at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at  at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at  at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender cannot be found by ch.qos.logback.classic_1.1.2.v20160208-0839
    at  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
    at  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:60)
    at  ... 17 common frames omitted
09:54:48,137 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:81 - ActionException in Action for tag [appender] ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.begin(AppenderAction.java:82)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:275)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:147)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:129)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
    at  at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:185)
    at  at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at  at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at  at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at  at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at  at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:73)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:48)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:35)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.begin(AppenderAction.java:54)
    at  ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender cannot be found by ch.qos.logback.classic_1.1.2.v20160208-0839
    at  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
    at  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:60)
    at  ... 17 common frames omitted
09:54:48,137 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender.EclipseLogAppender]
09:54:48,137 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [EclipseLog]
09:54:48,139 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender.MavenConsoleAppender]
09:54:48,139 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [MavenConsoleLog]
09:54:48,140 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
09:54:48,140 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Could not find an appender named [FILE]. Did you define it below instead of above in the configuration file?
09:54:48,140 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - See http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order for more details.
09:54:48,140 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
09:54:48,140 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [EclipseLog] to Logger[ROOT]
09:54:48,140 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [MavenConsoleLog] to Logger[ROOT]
09:54:48,140 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.ning.http.client] to INFO
09:54:48,140 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
09:54:48,141 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@75ec60c3 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.core.templates.TemplateProcessor).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

`JAVA_HOME` is set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

trying to find that class shows:

```
/opt/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.1.RELEASE/plugins/ch.qos.logback.slf4j_1.1.2.v20160301-0943.jar
/opt/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.1.RELEASE/plugins/ch.qos.logback.classic_1.1.2.v20160208-0839.jar
/opt/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.1.RELEASE/plugins/ch.qos.logback.core_1.1.2.v20160208-0839.jar
```

I did have a prior version of STS installed and removed it (rm -rf) before untarring this latest version.  I've also tried removing the workspaces from my Documents directory and relaunching.

I'm running Ubuntu:

```
mfrederickson@artemis2:/opt/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.1.RELEASE$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Here is my java version:

```
mfrederickson@artemis2:/opt/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.1.RELEASE$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

I am not very experienced with java development.  Any help resolving this so I can get STS up and running would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: hard to say what exactly is going wrong here. I can see that your JDK is a slightly outdated one (JDK8 is at _152). Did you try to start STS with the "-clean" option? That might help the OSGi runtime to re-resolve bundle dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I tried with -clean and it did not help.  I also updated my java to 1.8.0_151-b12 and that didn't help either.

Comment: So is the dashboard the only view that doesn't work/show? And everything else works in STS?

Comment: @MartinLippert it appears so.

Comment: maybe there is an issue with the browser widget that we use for rendering the dashboard. What happens if you switch it to the old dashboard style (via the Preferences -> Spring -> Dashboard)?

Comment: The old dashboard style seems to work fine.  Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related to this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533176)